# FIFO implementation in VHDL: is read function deleting the element of the FIFO?

Tags: vhdl, fifo

```
library IEEE;  
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;  
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;  
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;  

entity fifo is  
port (  clk : in std_logic;  
        enr : in std_logic;   --enable read,should be '0' when not in use.  
        enw : in std_logic;    --enable write,should be '0' when not in use.  
        dataout : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);    --output data  
        datain : in std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);     --input data  
        empty : out std_logic;     --set as '1' when the queue is empty  
        full : out std_logic     --set as '1' when the queue is full  
     );  
end fifo;  

architecture Behavioral of fifo is  
type memory_type is array (0 to 255) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);  
signal memory : memory_type :=(others => (others => '0')); --memory for queue.  
signal readptr,writeptr : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) :="00000000"; --read/write pointers.  
begin  
  process(clk)  
  begin   
    if(clk'event and clk='1' and enr ='1') then  
      dataout <= memory(conv_integer(readptr));  
      error <= '0';  
      readptr <= readptr + '1';      --points to next address.  
    end if;  
    if(clk'event and clk='1' and enw ='1') then  
      memory(conv_integer(writeptr)) <= datain;  
      writeptr <= writeptr + '1';   --points to next address.  
    end if;  
    if(readptr = "11111111") then      --resetting read pointer.  
      readptr <= "00000000";  
    end if;  
    if(writeptr = "11111111") then        --checking whether queue is full or not
      full <='1';  
      writeptr <= "00000000";  
    else  
      full <='0';  
    end if;  
    if(writeptr = "00000000") then   --checking whether queue is empty or not  
      empty <='1';  
    else  
      empty <='0';  
    end if;  
  end process;  
end Behavioral;
```

In the above code I want to know whether the read function is also acting to delete the particular element which is being read?

If not can some one please provide a small vhdl code for delete function?

Answer (score 8):

The first problem is that he code, even when formatted so you can read it, is not very good.  You'd be lucky if it synthesizes at all, and if it does then it won't work very well.  The main problem is that there are multiple clocked and not-clocked chunks of logic inside the process.  If it did synthesize then there are still D-Flip-Flops that have nasty asynchronous set/resets.  It might be find for simulations, but I wouldn't want to use it "for real".

The second problem is that it's hard to know what you actually mean by "delete".

Given those issues, here's my best attempt at an answer...

Most FIFO's (including this one to a brain-dead extent) use what we refer to as a [circular buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer).   In a FIFO it's just a chunk of RAM that holds the data, plus a read and write pointer.  The pointers are used to keep track of which ram locations are being used.  Once a piece of data has been read, it is still in the ram but the pointers indicate that it's not used.  As more and more data flow through the FIFO, that ram location will eventually get overwritten with new data.

So, there is no concept of deleting data.  Only ram locations that are being used and not used.

Answer (score -1):

The following code is tested:

```vhdl
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity fifo is
generic (RAMsize: integer :=4);
port (  data_in: in std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);  
    clk,nrst: in std_logic;
    readReq: in std_logic;  
        writeReq: in std_logic; 
        data_out: out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0); 
        empty: out std_logic;  
        full: out std_logic;
    error: out std_logic);
end fifo;

architecture Behavioral of fifo is
type memory_type is array (0 to RAMsize-1) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal memory : memory_type :=(others => (others => '0')); 

begin
  process(clk,nrst)
  variable read_ptr, write_ptr : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) :="00000000";  -- read and write pointers
  variable isempty , isfull : std_logic :='0';
  begin
  if nrst='0' then
    memory <= (others => (others => '0'));
    empty <='1';
    full <='0';
    data_out <= "00000000";
    read_ptr := "00000000";
    write_ptr := "00000000";
    isempty :='1';
    isfull :='0';
    error <='0';
  elsif clk'event and clk='1' then
    if readReq='0' and writeReq='0' then
      error <='0';
    end if;
    if readReq='1' then
      if isempty='1' then
        error <= '1';
      else
        data_out <= memory(conv_integer(read_ptr));
        isfull :='0';
        full <='0';
        error <='0';
        if read_ptr=conv_std_logic_vector(RAMsize-1,8) then
          read_ptr := "00000000";
        else
          read_ptr := read_ptr + '1';
        end if;
        if read_ptr=write_ptr then
          isempty:='1';
          empty <='1';
        end if;
      end if;
    end if;
    if writeReq='1' then
      if isfull='1' then
        error <='1';
      else
        memory(conv_integer(write_ptr)) <= data_in;
        error <='0';
        isempty :='0';
        empty <='0';
        if write_ptr=conv_std_logic_vector(RAMsize-1,8) then
          write_ptr := "00000000";
        else
          write_ptr := write_ptr + '1';
        end if;
        if write_ptr=read_ptr then
          isfull :='1';
          full <='1';
        end if;
      end if;
    end if;
  end if;
  end process;

end Behavioral;





------ test bench:



library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity fifo_tb is end fifo_tb;
architecture fifo_tb of fifo_tb is
component fifo is
generic (RAMsize: integer );
port (  data_in: in std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);  
    clk,nrst: in std_logic;
    readReq: in std_logic;  
        writeReq: in std_logic; 
        data_out: out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0); 
        empty: out std_logic;  
        full: out std_logic;
    error: out std_logic);
end component;
signal data_in_t:  std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);  
signal clk_t,nrst_t: std_logic :='0';
signal readReq_t: std_logic;  
signal writeReq_t: std_logic; 
signal data_out_t: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0); 
signal empty_t: std_logic;  
signal full_t: std_logic;
signal error_t: std_logic;

begin
  u1: fifo generic map (4) port map (data_in_t,clk_t,nrst_t,readReq_t,writeReq_t,data_out_t,empty_t,full_t,error_t);
  nrst_t <= '0' , '1' after 15 ns;
  clk_t <= not clk_t after 2 ns;
  readReq_t <= '1' after 21 ns , '0' after 23 ns, '1' after 41 ns, '0' after 45 ns , '1' after 53 ns;
  writeReq_t <= '1' after 28 ns, '0' after 31 ns , '1' after 33 ns , '0' after 35 ns, '1' after 37 ns, '1' after 45 ns, '0' after 47 ns , '1' after 49 ns, '0' after 51 ns;
  data_in_t <= "11111111" after 29 ns, "11111110" after 33 ns , "11111100" after 37 ns, "11111000" after 45 ns, "11110000" after 49 ns;

end fifo_tb;
```

Comment: -1 Instead of a wall of code, could you explain how you solved OP's problem?

Comment: Formatted code would be better. There is a formatting button for that.